# Why do one of my template tags in an html file django project doesn't work while some of them works in other html files?

Tags: html, templates, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I'm making a portfolio website for a school project. I've already make the portfolio project page running with template tags working. Project title is showing, all the details, and even the image from the image field model is working.
[Look of my working project.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAoHC.jpg)
project.html file:

```
    <h1>{{ P_Info.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ P_Info.project_description }}</p>
    <p>Created on: {{ P_Info.date_created }}</p>
    <img src={{P_Info.artwork.url}}>
```

But somehow, when I try using template tags in other html files it doesn't work.
[Look of my non working home.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkH4Q.png)
[Look of my another non working about.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfG7C.png)
home.html file:

```
    <h2>Sample Occupation: {{ H_info.occupation }}</h2>
    <h1>Sample Name: {{ H_info.lastname }}, {{ H_info.firstname }}</h1>
    <h4>Sample Description: {{ H_info.short_description }}</h4>
```

about.html file:

```
<h1>About</h1>
    <p>Sample Description: {{Abt_Info.long_description}}</p>
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Sample Contact Number: {{Abt_Info.contact_number}}</p>
        </li>
        {% for x in Cont_Info %}
        <li>
            <a href={{x.site_link}}>Sample Site: {{x.site_name}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <img src={{Abt_Info.photo.url}} alt="User Photo">
```

here's my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import About_Info, Contact_Links, Category, Project_Info, Home_Info
# Create your views here.

def about(request):
    Abt_Info = About_Info.objects.all().values()
    Cont_Info = Contact_Links.objects.all().values()
    template = loader.get_template('about.html')
    context ={
        'Abt_Info':Abt_Info,
        'Cont_Info':Cont_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def project(request, project_id):
    P_Info = Project_Info.objects.get(id=project_id)
    template=loader.get_template('project.html')
    context = {
        'P_Info':P_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def home(request):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all().values()
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    context = {
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

my urls.py file:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/',views.about),
    path('projects/<int:project_id>', views.project),
    path('',views.home),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class About_Info(models.Model):
    long_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/id', default='default')

class Contact_Links(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    site_link = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Project_Info(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    project_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True)
    artwork = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/projects', default='default')

class Home_Info(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    bg_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/background', default='default')
```

and my admin.py file:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import About_Info, Contact_Links, Category, Project_Info, Home_Info

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(About_Info)
admin.site.register(Contact_Links)
admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Project_Info,ProjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(Home_Info)
```

At first I thought it has something to do with the naming of my template tags. I changed the template tags name multiple times. But then I realized that the naming convention works for the project.html file so I guess that's not the problem. I also tried starting from the beginning and changing my models. Before, the Home_Info class and the About_Info class are both in the same class called My_Info. I used that class model for both the home.html and the about.html and it didn't work. So I though maybe calling fields from one html file and then calling it again from another html is the problem. That's why I separated them expecting it to be solved. But as you can see, nothing has changed.

Comment: `H_info` loos like a set/list of objects. But you treat it like a single object in your template.

Comment: Yes, its a variable that contains the fields from Home_Info models. And when calling it in the html file, I use {{ H_Info.fieldname }} to show the value inside that field name. But apparently it only works on certain html files. What should I change?

Comment: As said, it looks like a list where you need to access it like `H_info.0.field_name`. Try to better understand what `H_info` is returning.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you, that was very helpful. What I did was put a loop in my in my template to display all the objects in the queryset. Like this:

{% for obj in H_Info %}
    <h2>Sample Occupation: {{ obj.occupation }}</h2>
    <h1>Sample Name: {{ obj.lastname }}, {{ obj.firstname }}</h1>
    <h4>Sample Description: {{ obj.short_description }}</h4>
{% endfor %}